# show iframed page actions in parent one

Tags: javascript, html

i have two html files with names A,B. that B.html included to A.html by iframe.
here is my **A.html** file :

```
<div id="show_message">
    <p> No clicked link yet! </p>
</div>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="B.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

now in B.html I have many links that I want Which of them cliked, show that URL in div id="show_message" ( in A.html).
here is my **B.html**:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="home"> Home </a>
    <a href="support"> Support</a>
    <a href="about"> About</a>
</div>
```

-- for example: when clicked link *home* in B.html , show *home* in div id="show_message" in A.html.

Any idea?

Comment: You have to at least include your attempt for us to help.

Comment: @WaisKamal realy i dont have any idea about that :|

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!! Try it...

Add a target attribute to the form within the iframe:

```
<form action="foobar" method="post" target="_parent">
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: good idea. can you explain more to how to show cliked link URL in parent?